# Write a prepared statement with nullable values in conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, nullable

Is there a way to write a prepared statement where a value is compared to another value in a condition and I don't know, whether this value is `NULL` or not.

```sql
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` = :a1 AND `a2` = :a2
```

If I would use this prepared statement with `a1 => null` and `a2 => 42`, then the resulting query would be:

```sql
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` = NULL AND `a2` = '42'
```

This is, of course, not what I want. I would need this in that case:

```sql
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` IS NULL AND `a2` = '42'
                                   ^^
```

Both `a1` and `a2` are nullable. I don't want to define 4 prepare statements:

```sql
-- I would use this, if both values are not null
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` = :a1 AND `a2` = :a2

-- and this, if the expected value of a1 is null
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` IS NULL AND `a2` = :a2   

-- and this, if the expected value of a2 is null
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` = :a1 AND `a2` IS NULL

-- and this, if I would expect both values to be null
SELECT `foo` FROM `bar` WHERE `a1` IS NULL AND `a2` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL provides a null-safe comparison  **`<=>`** (spaceship) operator. That specifies an equality comparison that will return TRUE or FALSE, and won't return NULL when either of the operands is NULL.

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT NULL=NULL
     , NULL<=>NULL
     , 1=NULL
     , 1<=>NULL
     , 1=0
     , 1<=>0
     , 1=1
     , 1<=>1
```

Returns:

```
NULL=NULL  NULL<=>NULL  1=NULL  1<=>NULL     1=0  1<=>0     1=1  1<=>1  
---------  -----------  ------  --------  ------  -----  ------  -----
   (NULL)            1  (NULL)         0       0      0       1      1
```

---

That comparison operation is essentially shorthand. The return from:

```
 a <=> b
```

Is equivalent to the return from

```
 ( a = b OR ( a IS NULL AND b IS NULL ) )
```

---

To answer the question you asked, we could write a statement using the NULL-safe comparison **`<=>`** (spaceship) operator, like this:

```
 SELECT `foo`
   FROM `bar`
  WHERE `a1` <=> :a1
    AND `a2` <=> :a2
```

---

Or, for a more ANSI standards compliant and portable approach, we could achieve the same result without using that MySQL specific operator, like this:

```
 SELECT `foo`
   FROM `bar`
  WHERE ( `a1` = :a1  OR  ( `a1` IS NULL AND :a1d IS NULL ) )
    AND ( `a2` = :a2  OR  ( `a2` IS NULL AND :a2d IS NULL ) )
```

Note that we need to pass in the value of each bind value two times. In the past, PDO has not allowed more than one reference to a bind placeholder. (Not sure if this is still the case in more recent versions of PDO.) The workaround, as demonstrated above, is to use *four* distinct placeholders in the statement, and supply the same value for `:a1` and `:a1d`.)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't knew that operator (and could have figured the solution with the `OR` out myself..!)

Comment: @stofl: I'm glad you found this helpful. To highlight something I may not have emphasized sufficiently... that **`<=>`** comparison operator is a *non-standard* extension available *only* in MySQL. (At least, I'm not aware of any other DBMS that supports this operator.)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. It is not relevant in my case, because we're not staying dbms independent anyways.